# How to remove all replication from a mongodb instance?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to setup my first database with replication.  I was going to use my local instance as the primary and a test server as the secondary.  Along the way things got screwed up so I would like to reset all replication and start from scratch.  I was hoping to just remove the replication members using:

```
rs.remove("some.server.com:27017")
```

on each member, but I get the error:

> replSetReconfig should only be run on PRIMARY, but my state is
>   REMOVED; use the "force" argument to override

I then tried adding the force attribute:

```
rs.remove("some.server.com:27017", {force: true})
```

but got the same message.  Even if this were to work, would it completely reset my replication setup?

What is the proper way to completely reset any replication that has been setup on a mongodb instance?

Comment: Have you `Shut down the mongod instance for the member you wish to remove`? per [doc](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-replica-set-member/#remove-a-member-using-rs-remove)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this by following these steps.

1. Get replica set config. rs.config()
2. Remove all members from config except primary itself.
3. rs.reconfig(updated_config)
4. remove all documents form `system.replset` --> `db["system.replset"].deleteMany({})`

See more information at [MongoDb website](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/remove-replica-set-member/#remove-a-member-using-rs-reconfig)

Comment: Yeah I ended up having to delete everything from `system.replset` nothing else seemed to get me back to square one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the remove commands from your primary instance (which you said was the local instance. Your primary instance will then tell the secondary it is no longer part of the RS.

If you just detach an instance from the replicaset the detached instance would keep the data, so you would actually need to remove that data from the detached secondary server. You can do this by deleting the contents of the data directory (/var/lib/mongodb/ i think)

[Resync Replica Set Member](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/resync-replica-set-member/#automatically-sync-a-member)